# Compute the line integral $\int_\gamma x \, dx$ where $\gamma$ is given by $g(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute the line integral $\int_\gamma x\,dx$ where $\gamma$ is given by $g(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ for $ 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi$.

Here is my work below and I end up getting 0, but the answer in  my textbook says $\pi$, and I am very confused why that is the case.

\begin{align}
& \int_0^{2\pi}\cos t \cdot (-\sin t, \cos t) \, dt \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_0^{2\pi}u^2 \, du = \frac{1}{3}u^3 \bigg]_0^{2\pi} \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac{1}{3}\cos^3(2\pi) - \frac{1}{3}\cos^3(0) = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3} = 0
\end{align}

If the textbook got $\pi$, I think that there is something fundamentally wrong with my setup or understanding because the integration didn't seem too difficult with a u substitution of $u = \cos t$ and $du = -\sin t$

Comment: Why do you use the "align" environment in MathJax without using alignment tabs?

Comment: Where you wrote $x\,dx,$ might you have meant $x\cdot dx,$ i.e. a dot product? (If so, you should work accordinly after that. If not then what do you mean by this product of two vectors?) $\qquad$

Comment: Because I don't know any better. What are align tabs? and yes I meant dot product

Comment: In your MathJax code you wrote $\backslash$begin{align} and $\backslash$end{align}. If you're not using alignment tabs, normally you would enclose the MathJax code between a pair of double dollar signs.

Comment: Alright. I will do that on stackexchange in the future more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $x=\cos t$ on $\gamma$, I get $dx=-\sin t\,dt$ and so the integral as
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\cos t(-\sin t)\,dt.$$
This comes out to be zero too.

The differential $x\,dx=\frac12 d(x^2)$ is exact, so integrating
it over a closed curve must give you zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $$\int_{\gamma} x\,dx = \int_{\gamma} (x,0)\cdot (dx,dy)$$
If ${\bf F}(x,y) = (x,0)$ then we have to evaluate $$\int_0^{2\pi}{\bf F}(\gamma(t))\cdot \gamma'(t)\,dt$$
Now, $\gamma(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$, $\gamma'(t) = (-\sin t, \cos t)$ and ${\bf F}(\gamma(t)) = (\cos t,0)$. Thus $$\int_\gamma x \, dx = \int_0^\pi \cos t (-\sin t)\,dt = 0$$

Comment: Okay so the book is wrong